# How to ignore sitemap url from Laravel routing?

Tags: php, xml, laravel, .htaccess, routes

I have `sitemap.xml` in the root directory of http://example.com

When I try to access http://example.com/sitemap.xml. It obviously throws route not found error.

So to try this changed `.htaccess` to look like:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Laravel version in use: 5.1.

But, no luck. How can I just make use and render manually generated XML file rather than serving from route? I am not looking for complex XML parsing theory here. Just trying a hook to escape from the specific routing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best approach is to move the sitemap.xml file to the **public** directory. You do not even have to worry about the routing as well.

Then it will automatically be accessible as http://example.com/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 2):

You can create a route that returns the dynamically generated sitemap. You do not necessarily need to return a file.

Ex.:

**Your routes:**

```
Route::get('sitemap.xml', 'App\\Controllers\\SiteMapController@index');
```

**Your SitemapController:**

```
public function index()
{

    $urls = Logic::getMyUrlsToMap();
    return view('site.home.sitemap', compact('urls'));

}
```

Logic::getMyUrlsToMap() is your logic to search for the urls that will be mapped.

**Your site.home.sitemap View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    @if($urls)
        @foreach($urls as $url)
            <url>
                <loc>{{$url}}</loc>
            </url>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</urlset>
```